# Solaris 8 - Root Password Reset Still Showing Expired

Tags: cron, solaris, password, sparc

I have a Solaris 8 2/02 SPARC test server that has an issue with the root account.  I am able to log in with this account but every time I do, I am met with this message...

***WARNING: Your password has expired. If you have cron jobs, they may fail. Please change your password at your earliest convenience.***

I have tried changing the password.  However, the message still appears when logging in.  I also do not want the account to expire.  So after I changed the password, I also ran the following command...

passwd -x -1 root

This disables password aging on the account.  I confirmed in /etc/shadow that it has been disabled.

I am not sure why this message still appears but it is causing my cron jobs not to run.  Any help with this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: can you please post the contents of /etc/default/passwd

Comment: @olivierg /etc/default/passwd
`#ident  "@(#)passwd.dfl 1.3     92/07/14 SMI"`
`MAXWEEKS=13`
`MINWEEKS=1`
`PASSLENGTH=8`

Answer (score 0):

1. edit /etc/default/passwd
2. put these 2 values empty:

   MAXWEEKS=
   MINWEEKS=

save, reboot, try again

Comment: I tried what you said and blanked out the MAXWEEKS and MINWEEKS in /etc/default/passwd.  Proceeded with reboot.  I still got the warning upon logging in as root.  I changed the password and checked /etc/shadow to make sure that password expiry had not been turned back on for root, it wasn't.  Logged out of the server and back in but I am still getting the warning.  I appreciate the help.